Delphi TListview and TLinkControlToField issues - cannot customise individual rows
I'm trying to use TLinkControlToField binding with TListview, with the event OnFilledListItem of TLinkControlToField.
However, as the data is filled in the TListview, I am able to customise the TListItemText but not the TListItemTextButton.
TForm1 = class(TForm)
  ListView1: TListView;
  PrototypeBindSource1: TPrototypeBindSource;
  BindingsList1: TBindingsList;
  LinkFillControlToField1: TLinkFillControlToField;
  procedure LinkFillControlToField1FilledListItem(Sender: TObject;
    const AEditor: IBindListEditorItem);
private
  FInteger: Integer;
public
  { Public declarations }
end;


procedure TForm1.LinkFillControlToField1FilledListItem(Sender: TObject;
  const AEditor: IBindListEditorItem);
begin
  var LItem := AEditor.CurrentObject as TListViewItem;

  var LTextObject := LItem.Objects.FindDrawable('Text1') as TListItemText;
  if Assigned(LTextObject) then
  begin
    LTextObject.Text := FInteger.ToString;
    LTextObject.Visible := (FInteger mod 2) = 0;  // does not hide
    if not LTextObject.Visible then
      LTextObject.Text := ''; // have to resort to .Text = empty to hide
  end;

  var LButtonObject := LItem.Objects.FindDrawable('TextButton2') as TListItemTextButton;
  if Assigned(LButtonObject) then
  begin
    LButtonObject.Text := 'test' + FInteger.ToString;
    // just make alternate rows invisible for testing purpose
    LButtonObject.Visible := (FInteger mod 2) = 0;  // does not make it invisible
    if not LButtonObject.Visible then
    begin
      LButtonObject.Height := 0.1;  // does not work!
      LButtonObject.Width := 0.1; // does not work!
    end;
  end;

  Inc(FInteger);
end;

You can copy and paste these components for convenience:
object ListView1: TListView
  ItemAppearanceClassName = 'TDynamicAppearance'
  ItemEditAppearanceClassName = 'TDynamicAppearance'
  HeaderAppearanceClassName = 'TListHeaderObjects'
  FooterAppearanceClassName = 'TCustomizeItemObjects'
  Position.X = 744.000000000000000000
  Position.Y = 120.000000000000000000
  Size.Width = 257.000000000000000000
  Size.Height = 401.000000000000000000
  Size.PlatformDefault = False
  TabOrder = 4
  ItemAppearanceObjects.ItemObjects.ObjectsCollection = <
    item
      AppearanceObjectName = 'Text1'
      AppearanceClassName = 'TTextObjectAppearance'
      Appearance.TextShadow.Color = claSlategray
      Appearance.Width = 79.000000000000000000
      Appearance.Height = 44.000000000000000000
    end
    item
      AppearanceObjectName = 'TextButton2'
      AppearanceClassName = 'TTextButtonObjectAppearance'
      Appearance.TextColor = claSlategray
      Appearance.TintColor = claSteelblue
      Appearance.Width = 50.000000000000000000
      Appearance.Align = Trailing
      Appearance.VertAlign = Center
      Appearance.Text = 'Edit'
    end>
  ItemAppearanceObjects.ItemEditObjects.ObjectsCollection = <
    item
      AppearanceObjectName = 'Text1'
      AppearanceClassName = 'TTextObjectAppearance'
    end>
end

object PrototypeBindSource1: TPrototypeBindSource
  AutoActivate = True
  AutoPost = False
  RecordCount = 5
  FieldDefs = <
    item
      Name = 'CustomerID'
      FieldType = ftInteger
      Generator = 'UIntegers'
    end
    item
      Name = 'CustomerType'
      FieldType = ftUInteger
      Generator = 'UIntegers'
    end>
  ScopeMappings = <>
  Left = 688
  Top = 184
end

Am I using OnFilledListItem wrongly? I need to customize each row.  I have partial success with the Text in TListview but not the TextButton of TListview.
Is there possibly a bug in the TextButton portion?
